# How do I prevent mariadb to reset timezone on restart?

Tags: timezone, mariadb

Every time in restart mariadb, it resets the timezone:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT @@global.time_zone;      
+--------------------+
| @@global.time_zone |
+--------------------+
| Europe/Amsterdam   |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> \q;
```

The timezone is Europe/Amsterdam. But when I restart it, it somehow changes to SYSTEM.

```
me@dbhost:~/ $ sudo systemctl restart mysqld;
me@dbhost:~/ $ mysql -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 9
Server version: 10.3.14-MariaDB-log Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT @@global.time_zone;
+--------------------+
| @@global.time_zone |
+--------------------+
| SYSTEM             |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Why is this, and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Time Zones](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/time-zones/):

```bsh
[mariadb]
...
default_time_zone = 'Europe/Amsterdam';
```